# Select spaces on double-click in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ / WebStorm to select all spaces and tabs when I double-click on spaces in code, as many other editors do, rather than select the enclosing line or preceding word?

E.g. when I double-click the spaces between `a` and `=`:

```
a     = 1;
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to the issue?

Comment: Nope... none yet

Comment: similar question for PhpStorm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222947/double-click-to-select-white-space-in-phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible in IntelliJ.
As a workaround, you could select/mark a space and use the shortcut [Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J] to mark all spaces in code.
With [Alt+J] you can extend the selection of the spaces one by one.