# Double click to select white space in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In Sublime I can double click whitespace in-between two characters in order to select just the white space, e.g. in:

```
$foo        = 'bar';
```

Would result in the selection of:

```
$foo████████= 'bar';
```

However in PhpStorm it selects the entire line.

Is there a setting I can toggle so that whitespace can be selected with a double click in the same way I can double click a variable to select it.

Comment: is this behavior still not possible?

Comment: Sadly not, they have improved how the cursor behaves when navigating amongst symbols, but the double click action is still the same. The open issue @Oldskool mentions in his answer is the best place to see if this issue gets resolved (but it _has_ been open for 6 years so I wouldn't hold my breath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There is [an open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110607) requesting the functionality you describe on the bug tracker, you could vote for this and leave a comment that you would like to see this functionality added as well.

Apparently, according to the comments triple clicking used to work to get this done. Although that was posted in 2013 and I cannot reproduce this on the latest version anymore, so I figure they removed that somewhere along the way.